# How to match fingerprint after getting data from database

Tags: android

I am working on a project in which i have to save fingerprint data on cloud on signup and then get back and match when signing in. I'm using SecuGen hamester device and sdk. I've saved the image data in base64 when signing up on app to my firebase database. When getting back the data and matching it on sign in. It's not working. Please help.

Register Image

```
    mRegisterImage = new byte[mImageWidth*mImageHeight];
        this.mCheckBoxMatched.setChecked(false);

        long result = sgfplib.GetImageEx(mRegisterImage, IMAGE_CAPTURE_TIMEOUT_MS,IMAGE_CAPTURE_QUALITY);

        mImageViewFingerprint.setImageBitmap(this.toGrayscale(mRegisterImage));

        Bitmap image = ((BitmapDrawable)mImageViewFingerprint.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,byteArrayOutputStream);
        encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray(), Base64.DEFAULT);

        result = sgfplib.SetTemplateFormat(SGFDxTemplateFormat.TEMPLATE_FORMAT_ISO19794);

        int quality1[] = new int[1];
        result = sgfplib.GetImageQuality(mImageWidth, mImageHeight, mRegisterImage, quality1);

        SGFingerInfo fpInfo = new SGFingerInfo();
        fpInfo.FingerNumber = 1;
        fpInfo.ImageQuality = quality1[0];
        fpInfo.ImpressionType = SGImpressionType.SG_IMPTYPE_LP;
        fpInfo.ViewNumber = 1;

        for (int i=0; i< mRegisterTemplate.length; ++i)
            mRegisterTemplate[i] = 0;

        result = sgfplib.CreateTemplate(fpInfo, mRegisterImage, mRegisterTemplate);

        int[] size = new int[1];
        result = sgfplib.GetTemplateSize(mRegisterTemplate, size);

        mRegisterImage = null;
        fpInfo = null; }

    if (v == this.mButtonMatch) {
        //DEBUG Log.d(TAG, "Clicked MATCH");
        if (mVerifyImage != null)
            mVerifyImage = null;
        mVerifyImage = new byte[mImageWidth*mImageHeight];

        long result = sgfplib.GetImageEx(mVerifyImage, IMAGE_CAPTURE_TIMEOUT_MS,IMAGE_CAPTURE_QUALITY);

        mImageViewFingerprint.setImageBitmap(this.toGrayscale(mVerifyImage));
        mImageViewVerify.setImageBitmap(this.toGrayscale(mVerifyImage));

        result = sgfplib.SetTemplateFormat(SGFDxTemplateFormat.TEMPLATE_FORMAT_ISO19794);

        int quality[] = new int[1];
        result = sgfplib.GetImageQuality(mImageWidth, mImageHeight, mVerifyImage, quality);

        SGFingerInfo fpInfo = new SGFingerInfo();
        fpInfo.FingerNumber = 1;
        fpInfo.ImageQuality = quality[0];
        fpInfo.ImpressionType = SGImpressionType.SG_IMPTYPE_LP;
        fpInfo.ViewNumber = 1;

        for (int i=0; i< mVerifyTemplate.length; ++i)
            mVerifyTemplate[i] = 0;
        result = sgfplib.CreateTemplate(fpInfo, mVerifyImage, mVerifyTemplate);

        int[] size = new int[1];
        result = sgfplib.GetTemplateSize(mVerifyTemplate, size);
        boolean[] matched = new boolean[1];
        int[] q = new int[1];
        result = sgfplib.MatchTemplate(mRegisterTemplate, mVerifyTemplate, SGFDxSecurityLevel.SL_NORMAL, matched);

        if (matched[0]) {

            String fname = null, lname= null, user=null ,passw = null;
            Bundle bn = getIntent().getExtras();
            fname = bn.getString("fname");
            lname = bn.getString("lname");
            user = bn.getString("user");
            passw = bn.getString("passw");

            Signupdata(getApplicationContext(),fname,lname,user,passw,encodedImage);

                            new IOSDialog.Builder(context)
                                    .setTitle("")
                                    .setMessage("Signup Successfull")
                                    .setPositiveButton("OK",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                            finish();
                                            Intent intent_name = new Intent();
                                            intent_name.setClass(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                                            startActivity(intent_name);
                                        }
                                    })
                                    .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null).show();
                        }
                    }
```

Retrieving and Matching

```
         byte[] encodedImage1 = Base64.decode(Finger,Base64.DEFAULT);

        Bitmap d = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(encodedImage1,0,encodedImage1.length);

        mImageViewRegister.setImageBitmap(d);

        long result = sgfplib.GetImageEx(encodedImage1, IMAGE_CAPTURE_TIMEOUT_MS,IMAGE_CAPTURE_QUALITY);

        result = sgfplib.SetTemplateFormat(SGFDxTemplateFormat.TEMPLATE_FORMAT_ISO19794);

        int quality1[] = new int[1];
        result = sgfplib.GetImageQuality(mImageWidth, mImageHeight, encodedImage1, quality1);

        new IOSDialog.Builder(context)
                .setTitle("Pointer")
                .setMessage(String.valueOf(quality1[0]))
                .setPositiveButton("OK", null)
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null).show();

        for (int i=0; i< mRegisterTemplate.length; ++i)
            mRegisterTemplate[i] = 0;
            result = sgfplib.CreateTemplate(fpInfo, encodedImage1, mRegisterTemplate);

        int[] q = new int[1];
        result = sgfplib.GetMatchingScore(mRegisterTemplate,mRegisterTemplate,q);

        new IOSDialog.Builder(context)
                .setTitle("Pointer")
                .setMessage(mRegisterTemplate.toString())
                .setPositiveButton("OK", null)
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null).show();

        new IOSDialog.Builder(context)
                .setTitle("Pointer")
                .setMessage(String.valueOf(q[0]))
                .setPositiveButton("OK", null)
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null).show();

    }
    if (v == this.mButtonMatch) {

        if (mVerifyImage != null)
            mVerifyImage = null;
        mVerifyImage = new byte[mImageWidth*mImageHeight];

        long result = sgfplib.GetImageEx(mVerifyImage, IMAGE_CAPTURE_TIMEOUT_MS,IMAGE_CAPTURE_QUALITY);
        mImageViewVerify.setImageBitmap(this.toGrayscale(mVerifyImage));

        result = sgfplib.SetTemplateFormat(SGFDxTemplateFormat.TEMPLATE_FORMAT_ISO19794);

        for (int i=0; i< mVerifyTemplate.length; ++i)
            mVerifyTemplate[i] = 0;

        result = sgfplib.CreateTemplate(fpInfo, mVerifyImage , mVerifyTemplate);

        int[] size = new int[1];
        result = sgfplib.GetTemplateSize(mVerifyTemplate, size);
        boolean[] matched = new boolean[1];

        int[] q = new int[1];
        result = sgfplib.MatchTemplate(mRegisterTemplate, mVerifyTemplate, SGFDxSecurityLevel.SL_NORMAL, matched);
         result = sgfplib.GetMatchingScore(mRegisterTemplate,mVerifyTemplate,q);

        new IOSDialog.Builder(context)
                .setTitle("Pointer")
                .setMessage(String.valueOf(q[0]))
                .setPositiveButton("OK", null)
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null).show();

        if (matched[0]) {

            new IOSDialog.Builder(context)
                    .setTitle("Pointer")
                    .setMessage("Matched")
                    .setPositiveButton("OK", null)
                    .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null).show();
            Intent intent_name = new Intent();
            intent_name.setClass(getApplicationContext(), UploadImg.class);
            intent_name.putExtra("fname",first_name);
            intent_name.putExtra("lname",last_name);
            intent_name.putExtra("user",user);
            startActivity(intent_name);
        }
        else {
            new IOSDialog.Builder(context)
                    .setTitle("Pointer")
                    .setMessage("Not Matched")
                    .setPositiveButton("OK", null)
                    .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null).show();
        }


        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Signupdata(getApplicationContext(),fname,lname,user,passw,result);
```

Remove the `encodedImage` from that line.